# Javascript redirection is not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, redirect, http-redirect

I am creating a mobile version of my application . This is a part of the settings page (mysettings.php).

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
     {
        echo("<script  type='text/javascript'> window.top.location.href='http://www.example.com/mobile/login.php'</script>");
     }
```

If the access_token is not set then it should redirect to the login.php but i cant understand why isnt it working.

In the rendered source code I can see because the redirection is not occurring is ( The redirection code exists )

```
<script  type='text/javascript'> window.top.location='http://www.example.com/mobile/login.php'</script>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>...
.
.
.</html>
```

I am using Chrome and this is source code from where I am logging to mysettings.php page

```
<?php
session_start();
$logins=0;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Settings</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
         <div class="ui-grid-a">
      <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="mysettings.php" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Settings</a> </div>
      <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="my.php" data-role="button" data-mini="true">My Pictures</a> </div>
    </div>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">

    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not perform the redirect in PHP?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney : How do I do that ?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney : If you mean by the header , That too didnt work . I get "Undefined" as the message in the source code  `
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/earnfame/public_html/mobile/mysettings.php:7) in <b>/home/xxx/public_html/mobile/mysettings.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />`


I am trying to access it from a php page with is mobiled based. Does this cause any problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `header` PHP function to perform a redirect:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/mobile/login.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Note that this will need to be performed before sending any HTML markup

Comment: Still not working .

`
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/earnfame/public_html/mobile/mysettings.php:7) in <b>/home/xxx/public_html/mobile/mysettings.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> `

Comment: @AdiMathur it must be sent before any other output

Comment: I placed it in the PHP before opening the HTML tag. On the window I am getting `Undefined` and the error in the source code as above. 
Please Help.

Comment: @AdiMathur the error indicates that the script mysettings.php is outputting something on line 7

Comment: There was a closing and opening tag on line 7 "?> <?php" . I removed this line but now from the option.php which loads this page now this is giving me an error "Error loading page" . I think its some JqueryMobile problem now.

Comment: I added data-ajax="false"  to  the button  on mysettings.php and it started working fine.   Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using the php `header("Location: http://some/url");` or also try to use `window.location.href`  instaed of top lastly try to put the script instead the document markup instead of before it (might work?...)

Comment: still its not working... I tried both header and window.location.href 

<script  type='text/javascript'> window.location.href='http://www.xxxx.com/mobile/login.php'</script>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>

Comment: hmm, pretty sure your issue is elsewhere then... if neither of these work you either have a fundamental JS error or perhaps JS isn't enabled or PHP isn't outputting correctly, check your PHP error logs, and your js console for errors

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
data-ajax="false"
```

to the button on `mysettings.php` and it started working fine. Thank you

Comment: ideally you should accept/upvote the correct answer, not add your own answer